# Modern and ancient word choice: 昔人 vs 古人 vs 前妻

Tags: word-choice

Older Chinese folks (古人) love to use 昔人，but they never use 古人 in their poem or lyrics. *(OR can someone give me an example where 古人 was actually using 古人 in their writing?)* For instance, a favorite poem from the tang dynasty: **昔人**已乘黄鹤去，此地空余黄鹤楼。黄鹤一去不复返，白云千载空悠悠。On the other hand, newer Chinese folks now rarely use the word 昔; instead, 古人 (昔人 old folks)，去年 (昔年 last year)，昨天 (昔日 yesterday)，前天 (昔日 the day after yesterday).

Why does the preference of certain word choices shift over time?

And since 昔 means 从前, technically, can we use 昔人 to replace 前妻/前女友？ OR does 昔人 have to be a 死人 (*an already deceased person*)？

Comment: bkrs：昔人 前人; 古人，从前的人。people of the past e。g。远托异国, 昔人所悲

Comment: 昔日 is not yesterday, it is just past day, generally it refers to a long past day.

Comment: "the day after yesterday" = "today"  (also, there really should just be *one question per question*)

Comment: can we use 昔人 to replace 前妻/前女友？: No.

Answer (score 2):

never? you're kidding :) the term "古人" is also used in poem.

just a casual search:

in [通典·卷三十二](https://archive.org/stream/06044428.cn#page/n72/mode/2up) (end of p73, and start of 74):

> 賦詩曰
>
> **古人**云此水﹒一飲重千金
>
> 若使夷齊飲﹒終當不易心

next, 杜工部﹒ [吾宗](http://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=71263&page=108)

> 吾宗老孫子﹒質朴**古人**風﹒耕鑿安時論﹒衣冠與世同
>
> 在家常早起﹒憂國願年豐﹒語及君臣際﹒經書滿腹中

later, 孟宗獻 wrote

> **古人**借宅亦種竹﹒大是饕竒心未足﹒髙齋聞有萬琅玕﹒坐對懐山飲秋緑﹒
>
> 官閒勝日無一事﹒尊酒不空仍有肉﹒他時剥啄叩君門﹒髙枕矮床容我宿

imo, characters are like fashion, "trendy" today, would out-of-date".

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

昔 becomes 书面语(literary word) nowadays.
昔人 can refer to anyone that has deceased.

Answer (score 1):

昔人 doesn't have to be 死人. Honestly, I've never heard anyone calling his ex 昔人, but I think it's usable. Maybe too poetic for daily life, and so you might need to explain it to people further, unless you use it in a poem.

故人 is a little more common than 昔人 in modern Chinese, but still, quite poetic. If you call your ex 一位故人， than probably you are implying that you two had a subtle past.